# "global" OCSP with Apache mod_ssl / Alternative to -VAfile option Openssl

Tags: certificates, openssl, apache, ocsp

## Context

I'm developping my own OCSP responder which signed its ocsp responses with its own self signed certificate caOcspBC.crt.
You can find it here : https://github.com/Dinou/ocspResponder 
I want to get the revocation status from a certificate RC.crt issued from a CA certificate CA.crt thanks to openssl.

All my certificates are located here : https://github.com/Dinou/ocspResponder/tree/master/src/main/resources/certificates

So, I execute this first command where I explicitly trust my ocsp certificate thanks to -VAfile option  :

`# openssl ocsp -issuer CA.crt -VAfile caOcspBC.crt -cert RC.crt -req_text -url http://responderurl:port/myServlet 
OCSP Request Data:
    Version: 1 (0x0)
    Requestor List:
        Certificate ID:
          Hash Algorithm: sha1
          Issuer Name Hash: 19266539D5B4B518D4382B2D3779CBF53A6061D6
          Issuer Key Hash: 89B91685082EF65F5611F965E94422D602BE27DB
          Serial Number: 0A
    Request Extensions:
        OCSP Nonce: 
            04106D042BFA97BFA61F5AAAD756C5619CF2
Response verify OK
RC.crt: good
    This Update: May 19 14:51:51 2014 GMT`

It works well.

If I don't use the -VAfile option I get :

`# openssl ocsp -issuer CA.crt -cert RC.crt -req_text -url http://responderUrl:port/myServlet 
OCSP Request Data:
    Version: 1 (0x0)
    Requestor List:
        Certificate ID:
          Hash Algorithm: sha1
          Issuer Name Hash: 19266539D5B4B518D4382B2D3779CBF53A6061D6
          Issuer Key Hash: 89B91685082EF65F5611F965E94422D602BE27DB
          Serial Number: 0A
    Request Extensions:
        OCSP Nonce: 
            0410C8D048BB5A49596A7714B4D74935E3C5
Response Verify Failure
140451402069696:error:27069065:OCSP routines:OCSP_basic_verify:certificate verify error:ocsp_vfy.c:126:Verify error:unable to get local issuer certificate
RC.crt: good
    This Update: May 19 14:52:09 2014 GMT`

It doesn't work. In fact my client openssl doesn't trust my ocsp certificate.

## Problem

But I want to use Apache mod_ssl with my generic OCSP, and there is no directive mapping to the -VAfile option -> I can not specify the trusted responder certificates.

## Question

What can I do to make my apache trust my self signed OCSP responder certificate ?

## Extra context

I tried many things :

- I imported my self signed certificate caOcspBC.crt in /etc/ssl/certs by using this :
  http://gagravarr.org/writing/openssl-certs/others.shtml#selfsigned-openssl (symbolic link)
  It didn't work (Same error as was mentioned previously ocsp_vfy.c:126:Verify error:unable to get local issuer certificate)
- In openssl ocsp documentation states :

  ``` If the OCSP responder is a ``global responder'' which can give details about multiple CAs and has its own separate certificate chain then its root CA can be trusted for OCSP signing. For example:
  openssl x509 -in ocspCA.pem -addtrust OCSPSigning -out trustedCA.pem
  Alternatively the responder certificate itself can be explicitly trusted with the -VAfile option. ```

So, I executed this command on my self signed certificate and then I put It in /etc/ssl/certs as was mentioned previously.

It didn't work (Same error as was mentioned previously ocsp_vfy.c:126:Verify error:unable to get local issuer certificate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question**

What can I do to make my apache trust my self signed OCSP responder certificate ?

**Answer**

First, the self signed certificate must have these following properties :

- KeyUsage : digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, **keyCertSign**
- ExtendedKeyUsage : OCSPSigning
- BasicConstraints : critical,CA:TRUE, pathlen:0

It must be in pem format.

Then, apply the following command to the certificate :

```
openssl x509 -in selfSignedCert.pem -addtrust OCSPSigning -out trusted.pem
```

And finally append it to the file specified in ssl.conf in Apache by SSLCACertificateFile directive